# How to use custom function ExtractAllRegex() as an array formula? [Google Sheets]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using @Wiktor Stribiżew 's custom function ExtractAllRegex(). The script extracts all occurrences of a Regex pattern. In the example, I extract all words in column A starting with "v_"

[Here is a Google Sheet showing what I'm trying to do.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hRIqIl52uBodyrXNKoCKVWcaKKubnXVqpxCDzAjS8ZA/edit?usp=sharing)

The original strings are stored in column A. The custom function/the matches are in column B.

Wictors function works great for single cells. It also works great when I manually drag the formula down the column.

Here's Wictor's original code:

```
function ExtractAllRegex(input, pattern,groupId,separator) {return Array.from(input.matchAll(new RegExp(pattern,'g')), x=>x[groupId]).join(separator);}
```

Description:

- **input** - current cell value
- **pattern** - regex pattern
- **groupId** - Capturing group ID you want to extract
- **separator** - text used to join the matched results.

The question is, how do I turn column B into a working array formula? Or, perhaps better, how do I modify Wictor's script so it accepts a range instead and auto-fills down column B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your script to:

```js
function ExtractAllRegex(input, pattern,groupId,separator) {
  return input.map ? input.map( inp => ExtractAllRegex(inp, pattern, groupId, separator)) :
  Array.from(input.matchAll(new RegExp(pattern,'g')), x=>x[groupId]).join(separator);
}
```

and changed the formula in B2 to

```
=ExtractAllRegex(A2:A13,"(v_.+?\b)",0," ")
```

See if that works for you?